# video-js: vjs-big-play-button isn't hidden after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, video.js

I'm using a Wordpress. After a click on video vjs-big-play-button isn't hidden, it only hides after video starts to play.
I tried the following jQuery:

```
jQuery('.video-js').click(function(){
jQuery('.vjs-big-play-button').hide();});
```

But I can't find the correct click event, I tried all classes I can find with code inspector in Firefox but nothing is working.

Please help!

Comment: Why not attach to the play function instead ? Related: https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/1633#issuecomment-61455195

Answer (score 1):

Probably because the "play" button is generated dynamically by JS, you should write your function using `on()`.

```
$(".vjs-big-play-button").on("click", function(){
    $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

**Here is a working example:**
http://jsfiddle.net/0ak9066o/

You can read more about `on()` event at jQuery official documentation: http://api.jquery.com/on/